# OpenCV identify lines in this image

Tags: c++, opencv

I cannot apply the HoughLines transform from OpenCV to the image I am posting. All the lines should be oriented to 15 degrees, but this results in lots of lines in several directions. How can I do this?!

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhgM7.jpg) is the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, hough won't apply here.. way too many white pixels.

You can however get the lines with some image processing. I would do like this:

1. Rotate the image, so that your lines are vertical
2. Isolate each line.

### Rotate the image

You can get the `RotatedRect`using `minAreaRect` of all your white pixels, and then rotate your original image knowing the `yourRect.angle`.

I suppose that your original image represents text. There are a lot of techniques in document analysis to "rectify" your image, i.e. to correct the *skew*.

### Isolate each line

You can use vertical (or horizontal) projection histograms. Basically you count the number of white pixels for each x (y) coordinate.
You can do this in OpenCV with the function `reduce` giving as argument `CV_REDUCE_SUM`. 
Now you can easily identify the *spaces* between the lines where the histogram is 0 (better apply a small threshold). Your lines will be between two consecutive *spaces*.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with FitLine? However your answer sounds promising. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you very much!

Comment: fitLine isnt line detection but line fitting.